# How can i resolve load issue on dataSources.ids?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, git-ls-files

Everytime I  switch branches in Intellij Idea I got this  error message,I am a newbie on  Intellij IDEA.Anyone one to point me in right direction please?

Failed to load data sources: .idea\dataSources.ids is corrupted. Backup copy dataSources.corrupted.20170313-030813.ids is created.

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur if IDE tries to open the file of an old format or if the file is indeed corrupted (was checked-in in such a state into VCS). The workaround is to delete the file and [**Synchronize**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html#synch) the data source in IDE (from [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/database-tool-window.html) - it can be opened via View | Tool Windows | Database) - it will re-generate the file.

Btw `.ids` file only contains introspected database information (about DB objects like tables/indexes etc) and does not contain database connection settings. If you want to share connection settings (password is not shared for security reasons) you should version `dataSources.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you @Andrey..where is the  Database tool window?sorry I am intellij newbie

Comment: Edited the answer, please open it via View | Tool Windows | Database.